# Удаление папок старше 3 дней с сохранением 10 последних папок с помощью ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

Есть директория "C:/TestFolder/backups". С помощью плейбука нужно удалять все директории старше трех дней, но при этом сохранять 10 последних созданных.
На stackoverflow нашел точно такой же вопрос с готовым решением:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: find all files that are older than three
      find:
        paths: "/Users/asteen/Downloads/sites/"
        age: "3d"
        file_type: directory
      register: dirsOlderThan3d

    - name: remove older than 3 days but first ten newest
      file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}" 
        state: absent
      with_items: "{{ (dirsOlderThan3d.files | sort(attribute='ctime'))[:-10] | list }}"
```

Но это решение не работает, потому что выдается ошибка:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'ctime'"}
```

Как я понял, дело в том, что на машине, на которой запускается плейбук, установлен Python 3. Но решений, как сделать то же самое с Python 3, я не нашел. Я не так давно пользуюсь ansible, чтобы такие вещи решать :( Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А выхлоп `dirsOlderThan3d` можно?

Comment: Увы, нет. Я уже удалил этот код, т.к. нашел другое решение с помощью Powershell, правда, оно сохраняет только три последние директории

Comment: Кстати. а чё за `paths: "/Users/asteen/Downloads/sites/"`? Это как?

Comment: don Rumata, уже не помню, но это скопированный код. Если модуль не win_file, а просто file, значит, это линукс, то есть путь в корневом каталоге. Я переделывал под винду, конечно

Comment: Ну для всех модулей `win_*` нужно писать виндовые пути. Что `C:\`, что сетевой. Потому что что в винде, что в линуксе ансибл по-умолчанию выполняется прям на целевой тачке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помог решить задачу пользователь англоязычного stackoverflow с помощью команды Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Downloads_D -Directory | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime | Select-Object -SkipLast 3 | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Код удаляет все папки, кроме трех последних созданных.